# VM ware Installation

Tags: vmware

I am planning to install VMware software in order to launch another OS while running my current OS. I have research something about it but still would like to ask questions on the common installation problem? Hope you'll share your personal experiences.

Comment: I have had no problems - install the OS using VMware's instructions and then if you have an issue search VMWare comm8unity or plain google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my personal experience, I have had several problems encountered. This includes corrupt iso, improper installation of the OS resulting to a not running OS and etc. I have found this thread and I believe this is very helpful for me during the process of fixing my error. http://www.techyv.com/questions/common-problem-installing-vmware-tools